# Bias variance dilemma (derivation in Haykin's Neural Networks)

Tags: decomposition, bias-variance-tradeoff

I have a question regarding a certain derivation of the bias variance dilemma. Generally, I guess I have understood the derivation in, e.g., Geman's Paper, or in books like Bishop's *Pattern Recognition*. But now I've read the chapter in Haykin's *Neural Network* book, and I really don't get it.  Maybe it's a kind of different bias variance decomposition. I'm referring now to the 2nd edition, chapter 2.13 "Statistical nature of the learning process" (in the 3rd ed. I think it's in the section "Finite sample considerations"):

In formula (2.60) there is a definition of the training error Epsilon(w) for a certain data set T. Then the operator $E_T[]$ is declared as exactly this training error, Haykin calls $E_T[]$ "average operator over the entire training sample". With this definition, the further formulas (2.62), (2.63) can only be right in an approximately sense, if $E_T[]$ is this average operator. The following derivation then looks a lot like in Geman's Paper or Bishop's Book: now the operator $E_T[]$ is used like the ensemble expectation over all possible data sets, but: in the end Haykin defines bias and variance as functions dependent on the weight vector $w$! How can this be? The optimization leads to a mapping $T \rightarrow w$ (sample $T$ encoded in weights $w$ by optimization), and if $E_T[]$ is now used as ensemble expectation operator (over all possible data sets), how can bias and variance then be functions $B(w)$, $V(w)$ depending on the weight vector. $w$ respective $T$ should vanish by the integration in the expectation operator. On the other hand: if $E_T[]$ is still used as an (empirical!) average operator over a certain training set, all the derivations before don't make sense anymore, and the result would be a bias/variance-decomposition for only one special training set.

The whole section on this issue looks totally confusing to me, even the definitions don't seem to be consistent throughout this derivation. I tried to figure it out for a long time now, and turn it right somehow. Maybe somebody is familiar with Haykin's book, and can explain, what's going on here...

Comment: In general, the bias-variance 'dilemma' is actually a trade-off. The more complex you build your 'universal approximator' (the neural network), the better it can model the complex relations in the real world. But this limitless flexibility comes at a price, which is a model with large variances on its predictions. Hence, a bias-variance trade-off between a more simple, but biased model, or a more complex one of which its predictions are subject to a large variance.

Comment: Hello Matchmaker, it's not like I didn't understand the Bias-Variance-Decomposition at all... - as mentioned, I can definitely understand the original paper from Geman, and a lot of other sources on this issue, that I've read so far. It's Haykin's derivation that I can't understand...